# An elegant way to count number of negative elements in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a data vector with 1024 values and need to count the number of negative entries.  Is there an elegant way to do this without looping and checking if an element is <0 and incrementing a counter?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You want to read 'An Introduction to R'.  Your answer here is simply

```
 sum(  x < 0  )
```

which works thanks to vectorisation.  The `x < 0` expression returns a vector of booleans over which `sum()` can operate (by converting the booleans to standard 0/1 values).

Comment: The vector is not converted to numeric (for later versions of R anyway) - sum works on logical directly.  This can be easily observed.  `x <- rep(c(T,F), 2^30-1)` causes my R session RSS to increase to ~8G.  `sum(x)` does not increase this.  However, `sum(as.numeric(x))` causes the RSS to increase to ~25G (and of course returns the same value).

Comment: If data set has NA values the command should be sum(x < 0, na.rm = TRUE). Otherwise it returns NA as a result

Answer (score 4):

There is a good answer to this question from Steve Lianoglou [How to identify the rows in my dataframe with a negative value in any column?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2009-November/412586.html)

Let me just replicate his code with one small addition (4th point).

1. Imagine you had a data.frame like this:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = c(1:3,-4, 5:10), c = c(-1, 2:10))
   ```
2. This will return you a boolean vector of which rows have negative values:

   ```
   has.neg <- apply(df, 1, function(row) any(row < 0))
   ```
3. Here are the indexes for negative numbers:

   ```
   which(has.neg)
   ```
4. Here is a count of elements with negative numbers:

   ```
   length(which(has.neg))
   ```

Comment: The OP has a vector so, something like length(x[x < 0]) would work.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions prescribed need to be tweaked in-order to apply this for a df. 
The below command helps get the count of negative or any other symbolic logical relationship.
Suppose you have a dataframe:

`df <- data.frame(x=c(2,5,-10,NA,7), y=c(81,-1001,-1,NA,-991))`

In-order to get count of negative records in `x`:

`nrow(df[df$x<0,])`